# What does it mean when an error shows multiple files in a Python traceback?

Tags: python, error-handling

I get the following error (edited out some parts, but same structure):

```
  File "./project/calcs.py", line 43, in getVar
    var = await olf.getOrg(*args, **kwargs)

  File "./project/subView.py", line 177, in getOrg
    undo = force.getLength()

  File "./project/stack/refine.py", line 89, in getLength
    for eTL in getLength():

blablabla.blablabla.issue: Can't redirect user
```

Am I supposed to look at the very FIRST error line to address the issue? Is it a chronology?

So in this case, I would be obliged to address calcs.py @ line 43 to fix that issue? I wouldn't be able to fix it by, let's say, addressing the 2nd error or the last one, correct?

Is that also the way to look at any python error trackback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at a stack trace which is ordered chronologically (oldest call first).  In your case this means `var = await olf.getOrg(*args, **kwargs)` ran first which then ended up calling `undo = force.getLength()` and then `for eTL in getLength():` which failed.

Comment: So I would always have to look at the oldest call first in any case? There are no cases where I would look at some error in the middle of the stack trace?

Comment: You typically look at the newest frame (last call) when trying to figure out what cause the problem.  This will typically have to look at previous (frames) to figure out where the data came from.  You then form a theory, maybe make a change, and you execute your code again which happens oldest first.  Make sense?

Comment: (the next step, btw, is to employ a debugger pdb to stop your process somewhere, inspect variables, try run some code interactively, continue a little more etc)